# re.sub change the direction of the replaced Persian/Arabic content

Tags: python, regex, arabic, python-re, farsi

**Here is my code:**

```py
import re

CUSTOMIZED_SUB_PATTERN = "\{{\{{(?:\s)*{tag_key}(?:\s)*\|(?:\s)*([^|}}]+)(?:\s)*\}}\}}"
pattern = re.compile(CUSTOMIZED_SUB_PATTERN.format(tag_key='name'))
title = "عزیز {{ name | default value 1}} سلام"
re.sub(pattern, "محمد", title)
```

**The output:**

```
'عزیز محمد سلام'
```

**But what I want is:**

```
'سلام محمد عزیز'
```

So as you can see the direction of the sentence has been changed over the replacement.

**Question:**
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @Mandy8055 thanks again for the link please check comments on the first answers. So I think this won't help me out. Am I right?

Comment: You mean at first, I should reshape both of the strings and then replace them with re? Do you think the pattern will be able to capture the reshaped string?

Comment: thanks dude. I'll work on what you said

Comment: Try [this code snippet](https://tio.run/##lU89T8MwEN3zK05eEpOqKmWlSP0aGPgQTRcwRG5xQ0Q@LNdBVIk3uvV/MCGkMvFPHPFjgmtlZOGkOz3d3Xv3jm/kU56dNE2c8lxIECxir44zns@Cq4vz2@kknM1H4fUwCKY3lzAAVJog66NS0ih8ZhtlMKlM8e4eKqXufWywMoEcTqVkIjMkK9pd5imPE@b9rd1d5SKl0mt1B25GU@Zi7HARZ/K/JBnLhB3s6m@9/9npPZQlHIZQwSNb0aRg8GLrsVKgv@o3/V5vUXsMECn6vf4Egd96XxcLT7iEl0NBF/FS@W4HXLs0IiQ67Z1ZPDbd9mvLQPVWf5j8RB2wjjAG3DS/) (uses PyPi regex module). It sets the LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE at the start of the string and wraps each Arabic word with the `\u202B`/`\u202C` marks ensuring right-to-left order for Arabic words.

Comment: How generous you are. thank you and let me check

Comment: It should be `title = "سلام {{ name | defalue value 1}} عزیز"` but currently it is `title = "عزیز {{ name | defalue value 1}} سلام"`. You wrote it the wrong way around. [**See live demo here**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYvLOTQ4xN/XM8rVJT441Ck@wDEkxDXIT8FWQSmmuhqINOytYoo1tapLEtPjs1Mra6H8mBooQyM6rqa2NlZbEyZRWwtESlwFiSUlqUV5QIOKUvWS83MLMnNSNbBbppeWX5SbWKIBtcJWPS8xN1VdU5OrJLMkJxXklBubb7bcWH6zVaG6WgEkqVCjkJKalphTmqpQBiYNa2sVbuy8sel2z41NSlxcBUWZeSUaQIuLS5M0oC7RUVC62XpjLRCvV9JRAButqfn/PwA)

Comment: @revo thanks for your response. you know this the way we usually write the sentences (Right to Left) and that's the way someone can understand what I wrote in my lang. If I changed my sentence as you suggested it won't be a meaningful sentence.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I appreciate your response. It works thank you so much.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes absolutely.

Comment: Farsi is my native language and that's meaningful. What you wrote is like writing an English sentence with words that are placed in wrong spots. That's weird.

Comment: @revo Salam :), thanks for your response, I didn't get your point dude, but if I want to clarify it, think about it as a whole person right to left (سلام خوبی؟) text with some structures in it. So I have to find the structures and fill them with other words. it'd be appreciated if you put your opinions as an answer here and let me understand what you mean.

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi salam refigh, mokhelsam. All I'm saying is that if you first type your sentence with no placeholders, as is, i.e. `سلام محمد عزیز` then substitute `محمد` with  `{{ name | defalue value 1}}` your replacement string would be `سلام {{ name | defalue value 1}} عزیز` and not `عزیز {{ name | defalue value 1}} سلام`. I hope you understand my point now.

Comment: @revo thank you so much, bro, actually, that was my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`bidi`**](https://pypi.org/project/python-bidi/) and [**`arabic_reshaper`**](https://pypi.org/project/arabic-reshaper/) libraries in order to reshape and replace the RTL text accordingly.

> There is a special option in *get_Display()* method which is `base_dir` which has ‘L’ or ‘R’, override the calculated base_level.

You may try:

```
import re
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

title = "عزیز {{ name | defalue value 1}} سلام"
substr = "محمد"
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(title) 
new_title = get_display(reshaped_text, base_dir = 'L') # 'L' option indicates the text to appear from Left to Right. By default; it is RTL for Arabic texts.       
reshaped_text2 = arabic_reshaper.reshape(substr)
new_substr = get_display(reshaped_text2, base_dir = 'L')

CUSTOMIZED_SUB_PATTERN = "\{{\{{(?:\s)*{tag_key}(?:\s)*\|(?:\s)*([^|}}]+)(?:\s)*\}}\}}"
pattern = re.compile(CUSTOMIZED_SUB_PATTERN.format(tag_key='name'))
print(re.sub(pattern, new_substr, new_title))
```

You can find the sample run result of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/BlueMediumProducts)

Answer (score 0):

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Scheherazade', 'Janna LT Bold.ttf'))

page = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=A4)
page.setFont('Scheherazade', 12)
text_to_be_reshaped = 'اللغة العربية رائعة'
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
page.drawString(10*mm, 267*mm, bidi_text) 
page.showPage()
page.save()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

this answer is incorrect

```
>>> x = 'walk down street'
>>> x.split(' ')
['walk', 'down', 'street']
>>> x.split(' ')[::-1]
['street', 'down', 'walk']
>>> ' '.join(x.split(' ')[::-1])
'street down walk'
```

hope i helped!

Comment: it won't work, since this is a direction error, it will mess up things more.

Answer (score -1):

by this module you can correct your text shape an direction. just install pips and use it.

```
# install: pip install --upgrade arabic-reshaper
import arabic_reshaper

# install: pip install python-bidi
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text = "ذهب الطالب الى المدرسة"
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)    # correct its shape
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)           # correct its direction
```

Comment: reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(re.sub(pattern, "محمد", title))  and get_display(reshaped_text) lead me to ```'ﻡﻼﺳ ﺪﻤﺤﻣ ﺰﯾﺰﻋ'```

Comment: Hi @DeltaHaxor; IMHO when you provide the answer please do add the things needed in the question. and please at least provide a sample run result. It might help the OP.